# Use variable value from window resize function in another function

Tags: javascript

I have a carousel that I'm trying to get the currently visible number of slides to announce on "next" button click.

I'm able to see that on resize, I have the correct number of slides being logged, but can't seem to pass the `visibleSlides` value to the `getSlideCount` function properly.

The screen reader is reading "Next undefined items", instead of "Next {number} items"

How can I properly pass the value from the resize function to my next item click function?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
   let visibleSlides = $(".carousel-item.slick-active").length;
   getSlideCount(visibleSlides)
});
            
function getSlideCount(visibleSlides){
   return visibleSlides;
}
getSlideCount();
$(".slick-next").click(function(){
    $("#counter").append(`Next ${getSlideCount()} items`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `getSlideCount()` without `argument`. Change to this.

```
let visibleSlides;
$(window).resize(function () {
    visibleSlides = $(".carousel-item.slick-active").length;
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    visibleSlides = $(".carousel-item.slick-active").length;
});

$(".slick-next").click(function(){
    $("#counter").append(`Next ${visibleSlides} items`);
});
```

Comment: I see, thanks! As this only works on resize, how would this work on load? `$(window).on('load', function(){})`?